# Remove underscore at once in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I wanted to convert the string 2018_12_03 to 20181203.

Now I found a solution how I can do it.

```
$varName =~ s#_##;
```

**Output**

> 201812_03

To remove the second underscore I've just did the same again.

```
$varName =~ s#_##;
$varName =~ s#_##;
```

**Output 2**

> 20181203

It works but it doesn't look so nice, so my question is, is it possible to remove all underscores at once?

Comment: That's what `/g` "modifier" is for ("global"), so `s/_//g`.  Read a tutorial, like [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to delete all occurrences of a single character, you can use *transliteration* instead of substitution.

```
$varName =~ tr/_//d;
```

The `/d` means "delete": characters that have nothing to transliterate to will be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Regex replace by default only replaces the first match. You can replace all matches by specifying the [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) `g`:

```
$varName =~ s#_##g;
```